# Не могу сделать адаптацию на моб. устройство

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/ersul143/5crd0x2f/
Вот код, в этом таске нужно сделать адаптацию и нельзя добавлять бутстрап, не могу понять как можно это сделать добавил initial-scale 1.0, задал див блокам width 100%`введите сюда код`

Answer (score 0):

Используй везде где указываешь ширину %. Сайт сам подстроиться под это автоматически. Высоту указывай в пикселях.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]